# fb: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Any idea why I still get the error `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://homodigitalis.org/ from frame with URL` on [homodigitalis.org](http://homodigitalis.org/) even though I have followed [Facebook's recommendations](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/)?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){

    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId: '155692864582714',
        channelUrl: 'http://homodigitalis.org/channel.html',
        status: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone from FB says it's an expected exception, according to this bug report:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/122268321247958